# How can I declare a global pointer to unsigned char array and modify the value?

Tags: c, pointers

My main requirement is to declare an array and a pointer to it that can be read from and written to from functions throughout my program. So far I have done something like this, (Note, I even tried with pointer-to-pointer.

```
unsigned char *array_ptr;
unsigned char **array_ptr_ptr;
unsigned char array[20];

array_ptr = array;
array_ptr_ptr = &array_ptr;    

void main()
{
}
```

And then in another source file, I have a function

```
function(unsigned char *array_ptr)
{
    *array_ptr = value;
    array_ptr++;
    *array_ptr = value2;
}
```

I even tried with pointer to pointers.

```
function(unsigned char **array_ptr_ptr)
{
    **array_ptr_ptr = value;
    array_ptr_ptr++;
    **array_ptr_ptr = value2;
}
```

I cant seem to successfully write values, and even printing the values causes me issues. I also get segmentation faults.

Also, in a case such as mine, do I allocate memory using malloc to the array or the pointer?

Comment: Expose a pointer as a global variable???  ["Danger, Will Robinson!"](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_rsXUtnpJ6FM/TJmUGvdGZgI/AAAAAAAABI0/ZgiBK8OPtwE/s1600/DangerWillRobinson.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a double pointer. That most likely isn't working because the other source file doesn't have an `include` for the file where `array_ptr` is declared. I think best practice is to create a globals.h file and have it reference throughout the program.

Comment: I have created a header file and defined it as and 'code' extern array_ptr